# Conditional probability in conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have some general set $X$ with a finite measure $\mu$ (WLOG $\mu(X)=1$). We assume that there is a random partition on $X$ to "good" and "bad", and each $x\in X$ is either good or bad. For each $x$ define the event $A_x=$ {$x$ is bad}. 
Define $A$ to be the event that the set of bad $x$ has measure larger than $\epsilon$.

I want to show that there exists some $x\in X$ s.t. $\mathbb{P}(A_x | A)>\epsilon$.
 Intuitively, it should be clear that , since the measure of all the bad $x$ is larger than $\epsilon$, but I am stuggling proving it.

Comment: I think you have some basic concepts of probability mixed up here. An event is a measurable subset of the sample space; it doesn't make sense to define an event $A_x$ for each element $x$ of $X$. Nor does it make sense to define an event in terms of the measure of another event. You've defined $A_x$ and $A$ as random variables - in which case the expression $\mathbb P(A_x\mid A)$ is not meaningful.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. $x$ being good or bad, has nothing to do with $\mu$, it depends on the random partition on $X$.There is no problem defining $A_x$ as defined. How did you deduce that $A_x$ and $A$ are random variables???

Comment: @joeyg Your question is not formulated in the standard Kolomogorov model for Probability Theory and Math 1000 was right is asking all those questions. You are not getting an answer to your question because it is hard to understand the question Mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that $\mathbb{P}(A) > 0$, the answer is yes.  In fact, the set of $x$ for which $\mathbb{P}(A_x | A) > \epsilon$ has positive measure.

Suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure on the space of $\sigma$-measurable subsets of $X$, where $\mu$ is a measure on $\sigma$.  Then, by definition,
$$\mathbb{P}(A_x | A) = \frac{\int_A {1}_B(x)\;\mathbb{P}(dB)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$$
where $1_B$ is the indicator function of $B$, and the bad set $B$ of the partition ranges over all sets where $\mu(B) > \epsilon$.  Integrating with respect to the measure $\mu$ gives
$$\int_X \mathbb{P}(A_x | A)\;\mu(dx) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)} \int_A \int 1_B(x)\;\mu(dx) \mathbb{P}(dB) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)} \int_A \mu(B)\;\mathbb{P}(dB) > \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)}\epsilon\mathbb{P}(A).$$
It follows that $\mathbb{P}(A_x | A) > \epsilon$ on a set of positive measure.